# Hello, do you take / do passport photos?

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

If you need passport photos, and you go to a photo studio on the road, what verb is the correct to ask with, in the following context? I thought about:

1. Hello, do you **take** passport photos?
2. Hello, do you **do** passport photos?

But I am not sure which of them is natural, if any.

Comment: Either will be fine in a photo studio, although if there is a notice saying 'Passport Photos', probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Both of

> 1. Hello, do you **take** passport photos?
> 2. Hello, do you **do** passport photos?

are valid and natural, and both should be clearly understood by any native speaker. Three is no significant difference in meaning.

Sentence 1, using "take", is a bit more specific, and I would tend to prefer it. But that is largely a stylistic difference.

If one wants to emphasize not the taking of the photograph, but printing it and otherwise making it ready for the passport authorities, perhaps the more general "do" would be better.  But as a practical matter, either will **do** perfectly well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but 'do passport photos' is a more American English phrase than British English, right?

Comment: @Yash Laddha
 That usage is surely very common in US English. I would expect it to be understood in the UK, but I am not sure how common it is there.

Comment: Not very common I suppose. Thank you!

Comment: I'm British, but now live in the US and I'd tend to say "do" in both places. However, "take" sounds fine to me as well.

Comment: @DavidSiegel - In regard to services and products, I would regard 'do' passport photos, vegan pizzas, or bar mitzvahs, as less formal and more conversational than take, serve, or perform at, respectively, and not at all unknown or strange for UK speakers.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, where I live, and, I strongly suspect, elsewhere, people very often, casually and informally, say 'do you **do** *something*?' when they are asking about a product, service, or thing for sale, etc. The thing being asked about may well have a more formal verb associated with it.

> In a pizza shop: Do you do [serve, sell] vegan pizzas?
>
> In a photo shop: Do you do [take, provide] passport photos?
>
> To a comedian: Do you do [perform at] bar mizvahs?
>
> To a bus driver: Do you do [offer, sell] day tickets, or just single-trip?
>
> In a pet shop: Do you do [offer as a service] poodle clipping?